# Output window to file (Visual Studio 2005)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, window, customization

In Visual Studio 2005, how can I save what's written to the output window to a file (I can't change the code writing to the output window, and it writes a lot; I just want to save the output window content to a file)?

Comment: Too little information to answer. What language (C++, C#, VB.NET)? What framework (MFC, ATL, Windows Forms)? What output format (text, picture with snapshot of the window)? What target (entire window, a specific control)? Etc etc. Nobody can help you without more details...

Answer (score 6):

"File" -> "SaveOutputAs..." let's you save the contents of the output window to a file, but I imagine you want to redirect the output to a file while debugging? I'm still looking for a way to do that myself..

Answer (score 3):

You can just redirect the output stream in the command line arguments in Visual Studio.

Right click on your project → *Properties* → *Configuration properties* → *Debugging* → *Command arguments*.

After your arguments, just add:

```
> outputfile.txt
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. The OP is specifically asking for the output window. And this cannot be redirected easily. It can only be stored by using the File menu. BTW: I'd really like to have the option to permanently and always write the output window content to a file.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the output to the debug/trace window, you can capture this at runtime with [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) without running Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I just answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586933/how-do-i-redirect-output-from-the-visual-studio-debugger/2756199#2756199). I'm using this method myself to capture, filter and log debug output to a file on Windows Vista 32 bit. I use Visual Studio 2005 and work in C++, so this might help you too.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[ATLTrace Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khbh432d(VS.80).aspx) intercepts the ATLTRACE calls.  You can save the output of any process into a file.

Comment: That page now has the headline *"Visual Studio 2005 Retired documentation"*. Perhaps update your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing in .NET? And what is the code used to write to the output window?

In case you are using Trace.WriteLine or Debug.WriteLine you could use a TextWriterFileListener class to write all messages to a file automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If the app runs in a command window, you can use the old DOS redirect command ">" to redirect the output to a file.

For example.

```
c:\>dir > out.txt
```

...will redirect the output of the dir command to a file called out.txt. You should be able to do the same with your application.

This *will* stop the output from going to the console, but you can always go the log file to  get you the info you want.

Comment: There are programs that can be piped to, and will split the output (e.g. tee on unix systems).  This does _not_, however, capture the VS output window:  that one's populated by ATLTRACE calls, and can be captured by ATLTraceTool.