# How do I redirect output from the Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, debugging

In Visual Studio 2008, I can specify a message to be printed when a breakpoint is hit (by right-clicking the breakpoint and choosing 'When Hit...'). When the program is run, these messages appear in the Output Window. I would like to know, is there any way to redirect them to a file?

Specifying `>file.txt` as a command argument to the program does not work: this redirects the program's output, but not the debugger's.

(FWIW the behaviour I wish to achieve is to get the debugger to repeatedly print a variable's value to a file, rather than peppering my code with printf/cout statements.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Windows 2000, XP, Server 2003 and Vista [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) will capture:

- Win32 OutputDebugString
- Kernel-mode DbgPrint
- All kernel-mode variants of DbgPrint implemented in Windows XP and Server 2003

DebugView allows you to filter the output, add time stamps and log to file.

The catch is, you need to run without attaching to the debugger, for DbgView to capture the output. (Use Ctrl+F5)

Comment: what's the point in not using the Debugger if the output is generated by the breakpoints?

Comment: when you're debugging time sensitive applications and the very act of pausing the application changes the future state of the application.

Comment: that's not what i meant. The question was how the debugger output can be redirected to log the text that a breakpoint produces to a file. If the debugger cannot be use, no breakpoints would produce text.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was how to output to file the text generated by the debugger when a breakpoint is hit. This **requires** a debugger to be attached.

Answer (score 25):

1. Set the option *Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window*. We find it in *Tools* → *Options* → *Debugging* → *General* (fifth to last item).
2. Open the Immediate Window: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> or *Debug* → *Windows* → *Immediate Window*
3. Enter a command like the following in the Immediate window:

   ```
   > Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput /on C:\mylogfile.txt
   ```
4. To stop writing to the file, enter the following command in the Immediate window:

   ```
   > Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput /off
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but after pasting your `/on` command to Immediate Window, I get `The expression cannot be evaluated while in design mode.`  Any ideas?

Comment: In the Immediate window, commands must be prefixed with ">" (else, it is evaluated as an expression in the context of the debugged process, rather than a command of Visual Studio)

Comment: If you get `The operation could not be completed` when starting logging, you might be trying to write to somewhere that you don't have access to. Try `> Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput /on C:\temp\mylogfile.txt` instead.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of a way to write the output window contents to a file short of writing a VS plugin, but you can highlight the text in the output window and copy it to the clipboard, then paste it into a text file.