# How do I log Visual Studio 2017 build output to a file?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have my Visual Studio 2017 build logging set to Diagnostics mode, but the logging to the Output pane is truncated after a while so I don't get to see the whole log, which is of little use to me.

How do I redirect this to an external file, or increase the buffer size for the Output pane? The nearest answer I have from Stackoverflow is that the logging automatically goes to a file in the 'output' folder, whatever that is.

TIA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of the non accepted answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586933/how-do-i-redirect-output-from-the-visual-studio-debugger

Comment: All that answer achieves is to write the two given commands to the stated file. Build output still only appears in the Output pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to increase the buffer size of the output window. I have never heard of that option.
Inside of visual studio, when you build, it will only output to the debug output window. So there also no option to output instead to a file.
However if you compile with the command line, using msbuild.exe, you can log to a file while simultaneously outputing to the terminal window. This is how I set up all my builds. I output minimal output to the terminal window, while outputing much more verbose information to a file.

```
-verbosity:minimal -filelogger -fileloggerparameters:Verbosity=Diagnostic;LogFile=mybuild.log
```

More here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

Answer (score 4):

There is an extension by Microsoft available for VS 2017 that allows you to do configure logging for both normal builds as well as design-time builds (those that are used to determine project/solution structures and are used for the editing experience) at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProjectSystemTools

This extension will add a new tool window "Build Logging" that allows you to capture binary logs of builds:
[image: Build logging tool window]

These logs can be explored with the [Binary and Structured Log Viewer](http://msbuildlog.com).

Comment: This helped me figure out the command line parameters that roslyn was sending to csc.